# Localization using single resource file for Views in Asp .Net Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, localization, resources

I am working on localization and I want to create a global resource file for all the strings for all views. I created resource files for model, controller and view but I need a global type of resource file that can store key value pair for Views. I don't don't know how to achieve this and where should I store my global resource file? Should I store it in models or services or in controllers?

Comment: It is more than just models, controllers  and views... check this [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5061604/Developing-Multicultural-ASP-NET-Core-3-2-1-Projec) and [wiki](https://github.com/LazZiya/ExpressLocalization/wiki), this package offers an easy to implement [localization with one resource file](https://github.com/LazZiya/ExpressLocalization/wiki/One-Resource-File) as well.

Comment: @LazZiya I have edited my question. I need to know how can I store strings for view to achieve localization? and what should I use to store the resx file controller,services or models?

Answer (score 3):

in your `Resources` folder add the following files: (do your necessary imports of the code needed)

```
public class SharedViewLocalizer : ISharedViewLocalizer
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer localizer;

    public SharedViewLocalizer(IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
    {
        var type = typeof(SharedResource);
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
        this.localizer = factory.Create("SharedResource", assemblyName.Name);
    }

    public LocalizedString this[string key] => this.localizer[key];

    public LocalizedString GetLocalizedString(string key)
    {
        return this.localizer[key];
    }
}



public interface ISharedViewLocalizer
{
    public LocalizedString this[string key]
    {
        get;
    }

    LocalizedString GetLocalizedString(string key);
}


public class SharedResource
{
}
```

add a file called `SharedResource.en-US.resx` in the resource folder

in your cshtml:

```
@using yourdirectory.Resources

@inject ISharedViewLocalizer Localizer
```

also don't forget to dependency inject

```
services.AddTransient<ISharedViewLocalizer, SharedViewLocalizer>();
```

If you have done all this in your cshtml you can then do:

```
Localizer["something"]
```

which will write the translation on the html page.

someone posted this: https://medium.com/@flouss/asp-net-core-localization-one-resx-to-rule-them-all-de5c07692fa4

special thanks to him.

Comment: I tried but it's working in controller, but not working in view

Comment: I need more details

Comment: I copied your code and run in my local. Localizer["something"] won't translate the word. But I use DI in controller is worked.

Comment: You have to do 5 things. If any of the steps are skipped it won't work. Also, check the medium post in case. Hope you haven't looked over this: SharedResource.en-US.resx

Comment: If resx problem then won't worked on controller also. I followed the posted link added the `Data annotation localization` and `Controller localization`, that's why worked on controller. But the View part I followed exactly all yours code, add class `SharedViewLocalizer` ,add `SharedResource.en-US.resx` , `@inject ISharedViewLocalizer Localizer`, add DI `services.AddTransient<ISharedViewLocalizer, SharedViewLocalizer>();` and use `Localizer["something"]` in cshtml. But it's not working

Comment: you can refer my .NET 6 demo project, https://github.com/howardhee/TestLocal , I tried translate the "Welcome" word in index.cshtml